# MKPinAnnotationView image offset?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Does anyone have any idea why images used for a MKPinAnnotationView should be offset slightly (up and to the right) the code I am using is:

```
pinView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:pinView_ID];
pinView.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"TEST_Small.png"];
// RedCircleImage = 40px x 40px 72dpi PNG
// GreenDotImage = 2px x 2px 72dpi PNG
```

[image]

There are no changes to the code just a change in the filename for the image used, one image is the "the two red rings with a black dot in the center" the other is the "small green dot" I have added the thin blue lines in Photoshop to help show where the green dot is.

I have checked the centerOffset property and its correctly set to 0,0

Any ideas would be welcome.

Comment: I'm not sure that this is causing the problem you're seeing but you probably shouldn't be trying to customise MKPinAnnotationView. You should use MKAnnotationView. MKPinAnnotationView is a concrete implementation class and therefore may have it's own logic related to the pin animation that may be resulting in the offset you are seeing

Comment: Hi, thats a good point, I will have a look.

Comment: That was indeed the solution, much appreciated Dolbz, if you want the rep can you post your comment as an answer, otherwise I will mark the answer by omz.

Comment: That's exactly the same problem I ran into. I was customizing `MKPinAnnotationView` and it offset my image in a similar fashion as your screenshot (instead of dead center). Using `MKAnnotationView` solved it, and `centerOffset` is now automatically set to negative half of the image's dimensions.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As Dolbz has pointed out, you should use `MKAnnotationView` instead of `MKPinAnnotationView`. When you set the image, you can also set a `centerOffset` that is appropriate for your image. The default `centerOffset` should work for your images, but if you would display a pin, flag, etc. you would set it differently.

Comment: I spent several hours until I read your post and I realised that I was using MKPinAnnotationView rather than MKAnnotationView. Evidently centerOffset does not work in MKPinAnnotationView. Thanks a lot for help.